Convergence of a product of a general binomial coefficient
I'm trying to prove that
$$
a_n := (-1)^n\pmatrix{-\frac{1}{2} \\ n}
$$
converges to $0$.

We know that:
$$
 (-1)^n\pmatrix{-\frac{1}{2} \\ n} =  (-1)^n\prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{-\frac{1}{2}-(k-1)}{k} = \prod_{k=1}^{n}\frac{2k-1}{2k} = \frac{1}{2^n n!}\prod_{k=1}^{n}(2k-1)
$$

Since $a_{n+1} =\frac{2n+1}{2n+2} a_n < a_n$ and $a_n>0$ it follows that $a_n$ converges, but I don't know how to show that it converges to 0.

For an arbitrary $n>0$
$$\pmatrix{-\frac{1}{2} \ n}=\frac{\Gamma\big(\frac12\big)\Gamma\big(\frac12+n\big)}{\Gamma(n+1)\Gamma\big(\frac12+n\big)\Gamma\big(\frac12-n\big)}=\frac{\cos\pi n}\pi B\Big(\frac12;n\Big)\sim\frac{\cos\pi n}{\sqrt{\pi n}},\text{at},n\to\infty$$

Note that ${2n+1 \over 2n+2} = 1- {1 \over 2n+2}$, then since $a_n > 0$ we have
$\log a_{n+1} = \log (1- {1 \over 2n+2} ) + \log a_n$.
Also note that $ \log (1- {1 \over 2n+2} ) \le - {1 \over 2n+2}$, since $\log$ is concave, and so $\log a_n \le \log a_0 - {1 \over 2} (  1+{1 \over 2} + \cdots + {1 \over n})$ and so $\log a_n \to - \infty$,
